# Cloudformation cannot find hosted zone name when trying to add record set with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I'm trying to add a record set group using cloud formation.
I have two hosted zones in my region :

- app1.secretdomain.com
- app2.secretdomain.com

I want to add a record set to app2.secretdomain.com using this cloudformation resource:

```
  DNSRecordExistingZone:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: app2.secretdomain.com.
      RecordSets:
        - Name: prefix.app2.secretdomain.com.
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
            DNSName: !GetAtt [ CloudFrontDistribution, 'app2.secretdomain.com' ]
```

However I get an error from Clouformation when deploying saying 'no hosted zones named app2.secretdomain.com found'.

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the issue, TLDR :

**If you have multiple hosted zones with same domain (here 'secretdomain.com') you cannot use HostedZoneName but need to use HostedZoneId instead, as such**

```
  DNSRecordExistingZone:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: <YOUR_ZONE_ID>
      RecordSets:
        - Name: prefix.app2.secretdomain.com.
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
            DNSName: !GetAtt [ CloudFrontDistribution, 'app2.secretdomain.com' ]
```

This is actually mentionned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-recordsetgroup.html#cfn-route53-recordsetgroup-hostedzonename and I should have paid more attention.